# Хранение тегов в БД и работа с ними

Tags: теги, база-данных, mysql

В общем, столкнулся с задачей разбивки новостей по тегам.
Сделал по стандартному 3 таблицы:

- новости,
- список тегов
- связи.

С выводом/добавлением/удалением проблем нет.

Теперь, нужно расширить функционал и добавить возможность игнорирования некоторых тегов (иными словами, чтобы пользователь мог внести неопределённое количество тегов в чёрный список и новости с этими тегами ему не отображались).

**Как оптимально организовать запрос к БД при выводе списка новостей с учётом игнорлиста?**

Перепробовал разные варианты:

1. Проверять через **NOT IN**, присутствует ли данный игнорируемый тег в связях, но это работает крайне медленно, если заносить в чёрный список уже хотя бы 30 тегов.
2. Проверять напрямую, подцепляя **JOIN**`ом связи и игнор лист при выводе новостей и просто проверять, есть ли данный тег в новости и отсутствует в игнорлисте. Но тут проблема, что каждый тег дублирует новость, и приходится использовать **DISTINCT**. Оно работает быстрее первого способа, но всё равно не так хорошо, как бы хотелось.
3. Проверять с помощью **NOT EXISTS**, показалось наиболее быстрым способом. Но, может, показалось.

Может, есть ещё какие-то более оптимальные способы? Заранее спасибо.

**Обновление**

Не совсем понял Вас @Floyat. Тематики новостей разные. Некоторые пользователи не хотят читать про политику и прочее. Для того и делаю возможность добавлять теги в чёрный список. Собственно как сейчас работает **NOT EXISTS** мне нравится, правда записей сейчас не так много, меньше десяти тысяч и как он будет себя вести на ста тысячах или миллионе мне неизвестно. Так вот и хочу узнать лучший способ для вывода только подходящих новостей, исключая чёрный список конкретного пользователя.

Я понимаю, что скорее всего ни одному пользователю не нужно будет добавлять более 30 тегов в чёрный список, но всё равно.

Comment: Не выводите и все. Нормально юзер выбирает _что_ читать, а когда он выбирает что _не_ читать - это глобальный фильтр, который в перспективе вам даст 1 тэг из 1000000. Фильтруйте.

Comment: Тематики новостей разные. Некоторые пользователи не хотят читать про политику и прочее. Для того и делаю возможность добавлять теги в чёрный список. Собственно как сейчас работает NOT EXISTS мне нравится, правда записей не так много, меньше десяти тысяч и как он будет себя вести на ста тысячах или миллионе мне неизвестно. Так вот и хочу узнать лучший способ для вывода только подходящих новостей, исключая чёрный список конкретного пользователя.