# Фильтрация записей с определённым тегом

Tags: sql, оптимизация, mysql

Есть 3 таблицы: новости **posts - (id,postTitle,...)**, теги для новостей **tags - (id,postId,tagName)** и связи для тегов **relTags - (id,postId,tagId)**.

Задача: не выводить новости с определённым тегом (тегами). Для этой цели есть таблица **IgnoreTags - (id,userId,tagId)**.

Текущее решение в лоб: в условии вывода новостей добавляем такое -

```
 "AND ( SELECT count(id) FROM relTags
 WHERE p.id = postId AND tagId IN (
 игнорируемые теги через запятую )
  ) = 0"
```

Предварительно формируем "игнорируемые теги" из таблицы **IgnoreTags** для пользователя (например, если пользователь игнорирует теги с id 1 и 2, то будет так - "1,2"). Подключать таблицу связей relTags (через LEFT JOIN) и отбрасывать, так я тоже пытался, приходится использовать DISTINCT, и тогда всё работает ещё дольше.

Что делать? Как ускорить выполнение? Потому что в текущем варианте это работает ну очень долго (секунд по 5-7 минимум). Построение списка игнорируемых тегов через запятую выполняется очень быстро, а вот поиск необходимых новостей ужасно долго.

Я уже спрашивал подобное, но ответа не получил и всё это время пробовал всевозможные варианты: [Хранение тегов в БД и работа с ними](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/370514/mysql-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Так если теги уже есть, то чем `NOT IN (?)` не устраивает?

И тормозит может не из-за этого. Вы бы структуру привели с индексами (например, на http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Таблица связей для тегов не подключается при выводе новостей, потому что из-за неё дублируются все новости, т.к. тегов может быть несколько у одной новости. DISTINCT не помогает, с ним всё ещё хуже, чем с подзапросом в условии WHERE. Приводить структуру всех запросов и таблиц? Боюсь, это только всё усложнит, т.к. там ещё куча таблиц - рейтинг новостей и прочее. Дело в чём, если убрать условие для игнорирования, то всё выполняется мгновенно, только его добавляешь, сразу 5-7-... секунд. Если внести в чёрный список десяток тегов, то построение может затянуться на 10-20-... секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте избавиться от агрегатных функций в условии, например:

```
AND posts.id NOT IN (SELECT postid from relTags rt
Where rt.tagid in (список игнорируемых тегов)
and rt.post_id = posts.id)
```

Или:

```
AND posts.id NOT IN (SELECT postid from relTags rt
join IgnoreTags on IgnoreTags.tagid = rt.tagid
Where IgnoreTags.userid = @user_id and rt.post_id = posts.id)
```